matroid intersection and graph orientation
I am reading this lecture note and feel confused about the Theorem 6.2 there.
Using the notation in Section 6.1.3, we should prove that for any $U\subseteq A$,
$$r_1(U)+r_2(A\setminus U)\ge |E|.$$
I don't understand why this "edge" condition converts to the "vertex" condition $P\subseteq V$.

But $E(P)$ is a set of edges.

What I don't understand is why it is enough to consider edges inside $P$? What if $U$ has some edges connecting $P$ and $V\setminus P$? And why the rank of the second matroid involves only the vertices in $P$?

Have you red the footnote in page 4.

Yes, I think $U=A(P)$ gives $r_1(U)=|E(P)|$. But why it is enough to consider $U$ of this form? And why the sum of $k(v)$ there is related to $r_2$?

As mentioned before the statement of Theorem 6.2, when we use the matroid intersection theorem, it's enough to consider sets $U$ which are closed for matroid $M_1$. In the graph orientation case, $M_1$ is the partition matroid on $A$ where $I \subseteq A$ is independent iff at most one of $(u,v) \in I$ or $(v,u) \in I$ holds for all $uv \in E$. A set $U$ is closed in this matroid iff for all $uv \in E$, both or neither of $(u,v) \in U$ and $(v,u) \in U$ hold.
Therefore, if $U$ is a closed set, we can partition $G$ into two disjoint subgraphs:

Subgraph $F$, with $uv \in E(F)$ if and only if $(u,v) \in U$ and $(v,u) \in U$;
Subgraph $H$, with $uv \in E(H)$ if and only if $(u,v) \notin U$ and $(v,u) \notin U$.

To get an orientation from the matroid intersection theorem, we will minimize $r_1(U) + r_2(A \setminus U)$ over all $M_1$-closed sets $U \subseteq A$. We'd like to get at least $|E(G)|$, because a set of size $|E(G)|$ which is both $M_1$- and $M_2$-independent is exactly an orientation of bounded degree.
In terms of $F$ and $H$, we have

$r_1(U) = |E(F)|$: for every $uv \in E(G)$, we add $\min\{1, |U \cap \{(u,v), (v,u)\}|\}$, which simplifies to $1$ if $uv \in E(F)$ and $0$ if $uv \in E(H)$.
$r_2(A\setminus U) = \sum_{v \in V(G)} \min\{k_v, \deg_H(v)\}$: for every $v \in V(G)$, we add $\min\{k_v, |(A\setminus U) \cap \delta^-(v)|\}$, and edge $(x,v) \in \delta^-(v)$ is in $A \setminus U$ precisely when it contributes to $\deg_H(v)$.

So the sum of ranks simplifies to $$r_1(U) + r_2(A\setminus U) = |E(F)| + \sum_{v \in V(G)} \min\{k_v, \deg_H(v)\}.$$
To continue, we will show that we can make some more simplifying assumptions about $F$ and $H$. Let $P$ be the set of all vertices $v \in V(G)$ for which $\deg_H(v) \ge k_v$.

For as long as there is an edge $xy \in E(H)$ with $x \notin P$ or $y \notin P$, move $xy$ from $H$ to $F$: this increases $|E(F)|$ by $1$, but decreases either $\min\{k_x, \deg_H(x)\}$ or $\min\{k_y, \deg_H(y)\}$ (or both) by $1$, so we can only decrease the sum of ranks in this way. (This process might make the set $P$ smaller and give us more edges to move to $F$, but $P$ can't get smaller forever, so eventually we stabilize.)
For as long as there is an edge $xy \in E(F)$ with $x \in P$ and $y \in P$ move $xy$ from $F$ to $H$: this decreases $|E(F)|$ by $1$, and does not affect $\min\{k_x, \deg_H(x)\}$ or $\min\{k_y, \deg_H(y)\}$. (This process does not affect the set $P$.)

When we're done, $H$ is exactly the subgraph induced by $P$, so $|E(F)| = |E(G)| - |E(H)| = |E(G)| - |E(P)|$. (I would write $|E[P]|$ to distinguish the edge set of a graph $F$, $G$, or $H$ from the edge set induced by the vertices in $P$.) The sum or ranks $r_1(U) + r_2(A\setminus U)$ simplifies to $$|E(G)| - |E(P)| + \sum_{v \in P} k_v.$$ We obtain an orientation of bounded degree if, for all possible $H$ which are subgraphs induced by some $P$, this is at least $|E(G)|$; this is exactly the condition $$|E(P)| \le \sum_{v \in P} k_v$$ that we expected to get.
